# Can anybody please tell how to use web camera in ROS?

Tags: ros, uvc-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use webcamera to test images in ROS. I am programming using OPENCV and want to see the live video stream from my laptop in a window on ROS.  When I try to launch a file whose contents are given below, I get an error that "ERROR: cannot launch node of type [uvc_cam/uvc_cam_node]: can't locate node [uvc_cam_node] in package [uvc_cam]
No processes to monitor :".
I launch the file using the command : roslaunch ishan_vision uvc_cam.launch device:=/dev/video0

uvc_cam.launch file :

```
<node name="uvc_cam_node" pkg="uvc_cam" type="uvc_cam_node" output="screen">
    <remap from="camera/image_raw" to="camera/rgb/image_color" />
    <param name="device" value="$(arg device)" />
    <param name="width" value="320" />
    <param name="height" value="240" />
    <param name="frame_rate" value="20" />
    <param name="exposure" value="0" />
    <param name="gain" value="100" /> 
</node>
```

Can anybody please help?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193121/can-anybody-please-tell-how-to-use-web-camera-in-ros?/) by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2014-09-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like roslaunch can't find the node, which shouldn't happen if you've:

- installed uvc_camera `sudo apt-get install ros-<distro>-uvc-camera`
- sourced your ros installation `source /opt/ros/<distro>/setup.bash`

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-09-21**:
Thanks a lot. Now, its working. I did not install the uvc camera thats why it was giving the error. Thanks.

**Comment by [arzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21929/arzo/) on 2015-03-20**:
`` sudo apt-get install ros-`rosversion -d`-uvc-camera `` is shorter version

**Comment by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) on 2017-08-24**:
Dear Sir,

I have installed uvc-camera and have even sourced my ros installation.
However still roslaunch is unable to find the launch file.

Using ROS Kinetic

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try **uvc_camera** instead of **uvc_cam** and **uvc_camera_node** instead of **uvc_cam_node**

Also you can test your webcam with: **guvcview**

---

Originally posted by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) with karma: 258 on 2014-09-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eskay](https://answers.ros.org/users/33322/eskay/) on 2018-01-17**:
thanks...it worked

**Comment by [dolphinlove](https://answers.ros.org/users/36122/dolphinlove/) on 2018-06-30**:
Thank you! Using `guvcview` works for me!